# Need help understanding `map[String]type` behaviour in Go

Tags: oop, pointers, go, reference

Please have a look at this code:

```
package activity

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type Activity struct {
    yearContributions map[string]weekContributions
}

type dayContributions struct {
    Date         time.Time
    Contribution int
}

type weekContributions struct {
    Notation string
    AllDays  []dayContributions
}

func (currentWeekContribution *weekContributions) addContribution(additionalDayContribution dayContributions) {
    currentWeekContribution.AllDays = append(currentWeekContribution.AllDays, additionalDayContribution)
}

func (currentActivity *Activity) restore() {
    currentActivity.yearContributions = map[string]weekContributions{
        "Sunday":    weekContributions{Notation: "S", AllDays: make([]dayContributions, 0)},
        "Monday":    weekContributions{Notation: "M", AllDays: make([]dayContributions, 0)},
        "Tuesday":   weekContributions{Notation: "T", AllDays: make([]dayContributions, 0)},
        "Wednesday": weekContributions{Notation: "W", AllDays: make([]dayContributions, 0)},
        "Thursday":  weekContributions{Notation: "T", AllDays: make([]dayContributions, 0)},
        "Friday":    weekContributions{Notation: "F", AllDays: make([]dayContributions, 0)},
        "Saturday":  weekContributions{Notation: "S", AllDays: make([]dayContributions, 0)},
    }
}

func (currentActivity *Activity) Recalibrate() {
    currentActivity.restore()

    endDate := time.Now().UTC()
    startDate := endDate.AddDate(-1, 0, 0)

    for d := startDate; endDate.After(d); d = d.AddDate(0, 0, 1) {
        stringWeekday := d.Weekday().String()
        currentWeekContribution := currentActivity.yearContributions[stringWeekday]
        currentWeekContribution.addContribution(dayContributions{Date: d, Contribution: 1})
        fmt.Println(currentWeekContribution) // prints : {T [{2017-01-26 09:39:45.711238257 +0000 UTC 1}]}
    }
    fmt.Println(currentActivity.yearContributions) // prints : map[Tuesday:{T []} Wednesday:{W []} Thursday:{T []} Friday:{F []} Saturday:{S []} Sunday:{S []} Monday:{M []}]
}

func (singleDayContribution dayContributions) ReadableDate() string {
    singleDate := singleDayContribution.Date
    return singleDate.Month().String() + " " + strconv.Itoa(singleDate.Day()) + ", " + strconv.Itoa(singleDate.Year())
}

func (currentActivity Activity) GetContributionsForYear() map[string]weekContributions {
    return currentActivity.yearContributions
}
```

I am trying to append new `dayContributions` to the array `weekContributions.AllDays`.
`currentWeekContribution.AllDays = append(currentWeekContribution.AllDays, additionalDayContribution)` is the part `appends` to the `AllDays` property of the current type `weekContributions`.

The print statement prints the `weekContributions` array with a single member in the array. But the following print function says that all map values i.e. `weekContributions` objects have empty arrays as `AllDays` property.

My aim - To append `dayContribution` objects to values in map `activity.yearContributions`

I think -

1. The append function is working as intended as it appends 1 member on each iteration
2. Somehow, the `currentWeekContribution.addContribution` line [Line 48] is only appending to the local variable `currentWeekContribution` and doesn't update the corresponding value in `currentActivity.yearContributions` map

I am very new to `golang` and I think I am not following `the go way` / this would have worked in `java` or `ruby`
I don't know what this behaviour is called, so can't google search anything relevant.

Comment: @halfer updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two way you can do this.

One, You need to use pointer in as Map value. So that when you are appending in your local variable, you are changing through reference.

```
type Activity struct {
    yearContributions map[string]*weekContributions
}

type dayContributions struct {
    Date         time.Time
    Contribution int
}

type weekContributions struct {
    Notation string
    AllDays  []*dayContributions
}
```

Two, When you are doing following

```
currentWeekContribution := currentActivity.yearContributions[stringWeekday]
```

You are assigning a local variable. And you are appending to it. Now, you need to reassign that local variable. Like

```
currentWeekContribution := currentActivity.yearContributions[stringWeekday]
currentWeekContribution.addContribution(dayContributions{Date: d, Contribution: 1})
currentActivity.yearContributions[stringWeekday]= currentWeekContribution
```

Comment: Awesome @aerokite.. Thanks for this!